# Using TunTapDevice in Python with sendp doesn't fire the correct callback

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, ethernet, icmp

I'm using python-pytun to create two TUN interfaces (tun0 and tun1).  My goal is to create packet receivers on both interfaces, so when packets come in destined for their network, they'll create the appropriate response.  I'm using ICMP frames as an initial test.  The tun0 network is 10.8.0.0/29 and the tun1 network is 10.8.1.0/29.

When I run the code, I'm using sendp to send a packet from tun0 to tun1.  The weird thing is, the tun0 receiver callback fires and I end up seeing this output:

> [0] New Packet: 10.8.0.1 -> 10.8.1.2

With the program still running (since there's an infinite loop), I can send a ping to that interface using another terminal.  From that terminal I issue this command:

> ping -I 10.8.0.1 10.8.1.2

Which (I think) generates the same packet as the python code just did.  Regardless, when I do that, my python program looks like it's firing the correct receiver callback as shown here:

> [1] New Packet: 10.8.0.1 -> 10.8.1.2

Any thoughts?  Here's the code for reference.  Thanks for any input!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pytun import TunTapDevice, IFF_TAP
import os
from scapy.all import *
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

# Make sure we're running as root, otherwise report an error and exit
if os.geteuid() != 0:
    exit("Please run as root")

class Sniffer(Thread):
    def  __init__(self, interface, receive_callback):
        super().__init__()

        self.interface = interface
        self.receive_callback = receive_callback

    def run(self):
        print("Interface: {}".format(self.interface))
        sniff(iface=self.interface, filter="ip", prn=self.receive_callback)

class InterfaceFactory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.interfaces = []
    
    def create_tun_interface(self, interface, addr, dstaddr, prefixLen, receive_callback=None):
        # Looks like a TAP interface isn't what I want, but I'll leave the code here for now just in case
        #tun = TunTapDevice(name=interface, flags=IFF_TAP)

        # Create the TUN interface with the given name
        tun = TunTapDevice(name=interface)

        # Convert the prefix length to a subnet mask string in the form xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        netmask = '.'.join([str((m>>(3-i)*8)&0xff) for i,m in enumerate([-1<<(32-prefixLen)]*4)])

        # Assign network characteristics to the new TUN interface
        tun.addr = addr
        tun.netmask = netmask
        tun.mtu = 1500
        tun.dstaddr = dstaddr

        # I don't think I need to set the MAC address, one seems to be assigned anyway,
        # leaving the code here for debugging purposes.
        #tun.hwaddr = b'\x00\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55'

        # Bring the new TUN interface up
        tun.up()

        # Register the callback function if one was specified
        if receive_callback:
            sniffer = Sniffer(interface, receive_callback)
            sniffer.start()

        # Append the new interface to a member list to keep it within scope,
        # otherwise it would remove the interface from the system
        self.interfaces.append(tun)
    
    def get_tun_interface_handle(self, interface):
        for iface in self.interfaces:
            if iface.name == interface:
                return iface
        return None

interfaceFactory = InterfaceFactory()

def tun0_receive_callback(packet):
    ip_layer = packet.getlayer(IP)
    print("[0] New Packet: {src} -> {dst}".format(src=ip_layer.src, dst=ip_layer.dst))
    #packet.show2()
    #if packet.haslayer(ICMP):

def tun1_receive_callback(packet):
    ip_layer = packet.getlayer(IP)
    print("[1] New Packet: {src} -> {dst}".format(src=ip_layer.src, dst=ip_layer.dst))
    #packet.show2()
    #if packet.haslayer(ICMP):    

interfaceFactory.create_tun_interface("tun0", "10.8.0.1", "10.8.0.0", 29, tun0_receive_callback)
interfaceFactory.create_tun_interface("tun1", "10.8.1.1", "10.8.1.0", 29, tun1_receive_callback)

# Wait a second for the sniffer class to do what it needs to do
# not waiting will prevent the callback from firing
sleep(1)

# Send packet from tun0 to tun1, ICMP type 8 is Echo.  Note: type 0 is Echo Reply
# More info here: https://www.iana.org/assignments/icmp-parameters/icmp-parameters.xhtml#icmp-parameters-types
data = bytes(16)
frame = IP(src='10.8.0.1', dst='10.8.1.2')/ICMP(type=8)/Raw(load=data)
sendp(frame, iface="tun0")

try:
    while True:
        #frame.show2()
        sleep(2)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sniffer.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  When the software runs, I can issue a route command in Linux to view routes and both tun0 and tun1 are present.  I can also issue something like:

> ip route get 10.8.1.2

And it'll report tun1 is the destination interface.
I did find that Python (specifically scapy I think) needs to synchronize and reload both the interface list and the routing table.  Failing to do so will result in the software not knowing tun0 and tun1 are available interfaces or available routes.

To do so, I did the following:

```
conf.ifaces.reload()
conf.route.resync()
```

I can confirm that by viewing the interfaces and routes with:

```
print(conf.ifaces)
print(conf.route)
```

That also allowed me to replace `sendp` with just `send` since I'm only working  at layer 3.

Only new problem I think I have is when I run the software now, I have it sending out an ICMP request from 10.8.0.2 to 10.8.1.2 (so sending from tun0 to tun1).  That request is sent out ever 2 seconds.  While that's running, I start tcpdump on tun0 using:

> tcpdump -i tun0 icmp

And I don't see the packets going out.  I only see packets coming back.  I don't understand why that is.  Here's the updated code posted in case anyone wants to take a look.  Note: it does contain a lot of unused code and arguments since I've been playing with it looking for an answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pytun import TunTapDevice, IFF_TAP
import os
from scapy.all import *
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

# Make sure we're running as root, otherwise report an error and exit
if os.geteuid() != 0:
    exit("Please run as root")

class Sniffer(Thread):
    def  __init__(self, interface, receive_callback):
        super().__init__()

        self.interface = interface
        self.receive_callback = receive_callback

    def run(self):
        print("Interface: {}".format(self.interface))
        sniff(iface=self.interface, filter="icmp", prn=self.receive_callback)

class InterfaceFactory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.interfaces = []
    
    def create_tun_interface(self, interface, addr, dstaddr, macAddr, prefixLen, receive_callback=None):
        # Create the TUN interface with the given name
        #tun = TunTapDevice(name=interface, flags=IFF_TAP)
        tun = TunTapDevice(name=interface)

        # Convert the prefix length to a subnet mask string in the form xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        netmask = '.'.join([str((m>>(3-i)*8)&0xff) for i,m in enumerate([-1<<(32-prefixLen)]*4)])

        # Assign network characteristics to the new TUN interface
        tun.addr = addr
        tun.netmask = netmask
        tun.mtu = 1500
        tun.dstaddr = dstaddr

        # I don't think I need to set the MAC address, one seems to be assigned anyway,
        # leaving the code here for debugging purposes.
        tun.persist(False)

        #tun.hwaddr = macAddr

        # Bring the new TUN interface up
        tun.up()

        # Register the callback function if one was specified
        if receive_callback:
            sniffer = Sniffer(interface, receive_callback)
            sniffer.start()

        # Append the new interface to a member list to keep it within scope,
        # otherwise it would remove the interface from the system
        self.interfaces.append(tun)
    
    def get_tun_interface_handle(self, interface):
        for iface in self.interfaces:
            if iface.name == interface:
                return iface
        return None

interfaceFactory = InterfaceFactory()

def tun0_receive_callback(packet):
    ip_layer = packet.getlayer(IP)
    print("[0] New Packet: {src} -> {dst}".format(src=ip_layer.src, dst=ip_layer.dst))
    #packet.show2()
    #if packet.haslayer(ICMP):

def tun1_receive_callback(packet):
    ip_layer = packet.getlayer(IP)
    print("[1] New Packet: {src} -> {dst}".format(src=ip_layer.src, dst=ip_layer.dst))

    frame = IP(src=ip_layer.dst, dst=ip_layer.src)/ICMP(type=0)
    send(frame)
    #packet.show2()
    #if packet.haslayer(ICMP):    

interfaceFactory.create_tun_interface("tun0", "10.8.0.1", "10.8.0.0", b'\x00\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55', 28, tun0_receive_callback)
interfaceFactory.create_tun_interface("tun1", "10.8.1.1", "10.8.1.0", b'\x00\x11\x22\x33\x44\x56', 28, tun1_receive_callback)

# Wait a second for the sniffer class to do what it needs to do
# not waiting will prevent the callback from firing
#sleep(1)

# Send packet from tun0 to tun1, ICMP type 8 is Echo.  Note: type 0 is Echo Reply
# More info here: https://www.iana.org/assignments/icmp-parameters/icmp-parameters.xhtml#icmp-parameters-types
#data = bytes(16)
#frame = Ether(src='00:11:22:33:44:55', dst='00:11:22:33:44:56')/IP(src='10.8.0.2', dst='10.8.1.2')/ICMP(type=8)
frame = IP(src='10.8.0.2', dst='10.8.1.2')/ICMP(type=8)

conf.ifaces.reload()
conf.route.resync()
print(conf.route.route("10.8.0.2"))
print(conf.route.route("10.8.1.2"))


try:
    while True:
        #sendp(frame, iface="tun0")
        send(frame)
        #frame.show2()
        sleep(2)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sniffer.join()
```